# Can't switch languages via keyboard shortcut in Opera

Tags: release-juno, keyboard-shortcuts, opera

I can't switch keyboard layouts (En/Ru) in Opera browser (newest version, 63.0.3368.94) via system keyboard shortcut, so every time I must switch them with the mouse in wingpanel, which is very annoying.

Opera is the only app on my system that behaves that way. (Yes, I have filed this issue at Opera's bug collector several months ago, but the problem persists.)

Comment: I will try to reproduce the issue at my test machine and I will let you know.

Comment: Hi, Hasan! It's been three weeks :) Have you managed to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to comment. I couldn't reproduce the issue. I have tried adding Russian layout too. And it works.

Comment: Thanks! So you installed two layouts (En/Ru) and were able to successfully switch between them in Opera via keyboard shortcut? That's good news. But on my machine switching in Opera still doesn't work... I don't know what to think and where to look anymore.

Comment: Please try creating an issue at github or you can also ask at elementary OS Slack channel.